# STASM how face feature detection works

Tags: c++, image-processing, feature-detection

i'm trying to work on STASM but the manual doesn't really explain how it works, i want to understand how does ASM detect the face feature in STASM. can you please help me. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please read the documentation cited in Section 7 of the Stasm 4 manual, which says:

Stasm is based on the Active Shape Model (ASM) developed by Cootes and Taylor [4,
14].

[4]  T. F. Cootes and C. J. Taylor. Technical Report: Statistical Models of Appearance
for Computer Vision. The University of Manchester School of Medicine, 2004.
http://www.isbe.man.ac.uk/~bim/Models/app_models.pdf.

[14] S. Milborrow and F. Nicolls. Active Shape Models with SIFT Descriptors and MARS. VISAPP, 2014. 
http://www.milbo.org/stasm-files/active-shape-models-with-sift-and-mars.pdf.